# exp function using c++

Tags: c++, function, exp

I can't figure out why I keep getting the result 1.#INF from `my_exp()` when I give it 1 as input. Here is the code:

```
double factorial(const int k)
{
    int prod = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=k; i++)
        prod = i * prod;
    return prod;
}

double power(const double base, const int exponent)
{
    double result = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<=exponent; i++)
        result = result * base;
    return result;
}

double my_exp(double x)
{
    double sum = 1 + x;
    for(int k=2; k<50; k++)
        sum = sum + power(x,k) / factorial(k);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Provide a self contained code snippet which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What values of `x` give you `1.#INF`?

Comment: Try using a long double variable type, instead of double. There is most likely stack overflow with your exponent function,like @Mystical said.
May I ask what the function my_exp(); is trying to do? Perhaps that would help me make an alternate piece of code for you to use.

Answer (score 7):

You have an integer overflow in your `factorial` function. This causes it to output zero. `49!` is divisible by `2^32`, so your `factorial` function will return zero.

Then you divide by it causing it to go infinity. So the solution is to change `prod` to `double`:

```
double prod = 1;
```

Answer (score 6):

Instead of completely evaluating the power and the factorial terms for each term in your expansion, you should consider how the k'th term is related to the k-1'th term and just update each term based on this relationship. That will avoid the nasty overflows in your power and factorial functions (which you will no longer need). E.g.

```
double my_exp(double x)
{
    double sum = 1.0 + x;
    double term = x;                 // term for k = 1 is just x
    for (int k = 2; k < 50; k++)
    {
        term = term * x / (double)k; // term[k] = term[k-1] * x / k
        sum = sum + term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you should just reduce max of k form 50  to like 30 it will work;

and one question your code work just near 0 ?